# IF statement and multiplying

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

I have an IF statement `=IF(C7="SR",Rates!$G$20,IF(C7="UC",Rates!$H$20,IF(C7="DC",Rates!$G$20,))))`

This works great and gives me the correct rate.  The next step I need is to calculate that rate with a value from another cell.  A simple `=SUM(D6*P6)` returns `#VALUE!`

Can someone please assist with this?  Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add formatting to the post to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with D6 and P6? (what's the value of both fields? numerical values?)
SUM(D6*P6) should work but I don't see what's the utility (just =D6*P6 would give you the same answer since you're not summing anything).